# configuring project ':app' failed to find Build Tools revision

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My android gradle build fails with a helpful error message

```
$ gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 24.4.1
```

I looked at the SDK version that Android Studio thinks I have installed.

[image]

It reports I have 24.4.1 installed, which agrees with my `build.gradle` file.

Also, I have tried installing the sdk with `./android list sdk -a; ./android update sdk -a -u -t 1` but still the failure persists.

I even tried putting a bogus `local.properties` file

```
sdk.dir=/home/admin/DEADBEEF
```

which gives

```
$ gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/home/admin/DEADBEEF' does not exist.
```

Also, the stacktrace doesn't seem to be much help because I didn't find this source file. So now I've started digging through the [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/) for [DefaultSdkLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/sdk/DefaultSdkLoader.java)

```
$ gradle --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 24.4.1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:510)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.4.1
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:93)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:89)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:673)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:610)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        ... 52 more
```

Before `DefaultSdkLoader` can use a build tool to compile the project, the

```
com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalSdk#scanBuildTools
```

is called using your SDK directory. A new `BuildToolInfo` is created, which uses `PKG_BUILD_TOOLS` type to find build tools. So, I just looked in my build-tools folder in my android SDK and, lo! There are no build tools for 24.4.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It happens because **Build Tools revision 24.4.1 doesn't exist**.

The latest version is `23.0.2.`
These tools is included in the SDK package and installed in the `<sdk>/build-tools/` directory.

**Don't confuse** the [Android SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) with [SDK Build Tools](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/revisions/build-tools.html).

Change in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
   // ...

}
```

Comment: right. digging through the code i'm slowly finding that 24.4.1 doesn't exist in my `<androidsdk>/build-tools/` directory

Comment: please mention /build-tools/ in your answer

Comment: For me I am using buildToolsVersion - 28.0.3, I have checked and it is there in Android SDK Path, still getting the same exception.I am stuck here for 3 days.Please help me on this.  MY Question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182192/updated-androidstudio3-5-3-not-building-android-project-caused-by-org-gradle

Answer (score 6):

also try to increase gradle version in your project's build.gradle. It helped me

Comment: hey man if I can up this one a thousand times I would! Thank you @kazimad you don't know how much you helped me!

Answer (score 5):

In my case issue was with wrong path to `NDK`.

If your project requires it please check it  in menu `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had c++ codes in my project but i didn't have `NDK` installed, installing it solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it also happens if you uninstalled some packages from your react-native project and there is still packages in your build gradle dependencies in the bottom of page like:

```
{
 project(':react-native-sound-player')
}
```

Comment: Make sure to remove the associated code in the `MainApplication.java` file after removing the `project(':react-native-sound-player')`

Answer (score 1):

For me, dataBinding { enabled true } was enabled in gradle, removing this helped me

Answer (score 1):

I might late but following worked for me.

**build.gradle**

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'`

In my case I was using old version that causes the issue.

**Done**.