# Updated AndroidStudio(3.5.3) not building Android Project, Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException:Unable to load Maven meta-data

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Updated Android Studio not building Android Project, before it was building.
I have checked with Proxy settings still it is getting same
Below are the exceptions after rebuilding the Android Project.

```
    org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Gsa2_NewMenu'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:400)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:381)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:136)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 148 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

Below is the app gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XX.XX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 13
        versionName "6.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories{
    maven { url "jitpack.io" }
    maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    /*implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })*/
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')

    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.11.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'


    implementation(name:'merchantsdk', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name:'ezetapandroidsdk', ext:'aar')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is the Project build gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have checked online, but none worked.I am stuck from 4 days, Please check my App and Project gradle files and let me know.Please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you please post your build.gradle file of project level?

Comment: Hi Priyankagb, added project build gradle file.Please check and help me on this.

Comment: There may b some version issue, please update all dependencies and gradle version and google service version

Comment: @Priyankagb, Could you please check with my app gradle file and please suggest me because I am confused what to be changed.

Comment: studio will suggest new version for each dependency, you can Alt + Enter to get suggestion and pick suggestion for a new version

Comment: make sure you are using the latest version of all jars and libs

Comment: I have updated libraries, jars but none worked still the same exception.I am stuck here for past 3 days.Please help me on this.

Comment: Try to use a new and empty project. You are using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` and it exists, but in the stacktrace is reported `3.3.2` (which exists) and it very strange.

Comment: I have tried with tools build 3.3.2, it is giving above mentioned exception.

Comment: @Naveen make sure your proxy doesn't block this site. I have faced a similar issue when my server has blocked this site `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom`

Comment: @Priyankagb, Thanks for your response, I have checked it, no proxy is added in AndroidStudio.

Comment: In Android Studio, no need to change any proxy setting. because it will be okay if you haven't change anything form the setting. So please check your firewall or server setting of your network

Comment: I have checked about Firewall, it is ok but still the exception exists.

Comment: Please check this URL into your browser, https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom
if .pom file get download successfully than there is no issue with the network.

Comment: Yes, It is downloading .pom file from browser

Comment: okay, is this runtime exception or compile time?

Comment: It is coming everytime when I build the Project

Comment: `maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }` in this line remove `name 'Google'` and add  `google()` below maven, may it help

Comment: I have tried it but still the same exception coming

Comment: Add the following code to the end of gradle.properties(Project Properties) file `gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3129`

Comment: @TonyBaby, I have added above code, but didn't worked.Still giving the same exception.Could you help me on this please

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge Your **Android Studio** Version is Updated to **3.5.3** as You mention on Title
and You are Using 3.3.2 Build **Gradle Version**. i think Gradle Version is Creating an issue try to update you Gradle Version to **3.5.0**, **3.5.1** or **3.5.2** [Gradle Version][image: 1]
[image]

in Your Project build Gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: Hi Vinesh, I have tried updating build tools version to 3.5.0, Still the exception exists everytime I build the project.

Comment: Your Android Studio Version is 3.5.3 try to update yout gradle to 3.5.2 or 3.5.3

Comment: I have checked with 3.5.2, 3.5.3. No luck, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add certificates in Server Certificates (preferences -> Tools ->  Server Certificates -> <kbd>Click</kbd> + <kbd>button</kbd> and add the `.cer` files over there.

To get the `.cer`, go to pom library URL and click on lock left side of the URL or developer settings --> security and download the certificate as `.cer` and upload in android studio.